# Form states expanded or collapsed not working

Tags: 7

I cannot get this to work. Visible/Invisible works for me but this doesn't. Have I misunderstood anything?

```
    $form['items']['delivery_address'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => '',
    '#collapsed' => true,
    '#collapsible' => true,
    '#states' => array(
        'expanded' => array(
            ':input[name="add_address"]' => array('checked' => false),
            ':input[name="delivery_type_radios"]' => array('value' => 0),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes it work:

```
   '#title' => 'bleh',
```

It kinda makes sense...